# Alerts notification icon can't be seen in WSO2 API-M Admin Portal 3.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am doing a POC to configure alerts in WSO2 API-M 3.2.0. I created a new "Abnormal Requests per Minute" alert in Developer Portal for an API with 10 requests per minute. I also enabled alerts in deployment.yaml file under <API-M_ANALYTICS_HOME>/conf/worker folder.

After hitting the concerned API for more than 10 times within a minute, when I login to Admin Portal to check alerts, I don't see the alerts notification icon on the top right corner. Need hints if I am missing out on something.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The API Manager v3.2.0 Analytics comes with a separate Analytics Dashboard to view the Alerts and Usages of the APIs. Up until, API Manager v3.1.0, The Admin portal is used to show the Alerts. However, that is changed in APIM v3.2.0.

Execute the following command from the Analytics node to start the Dashboard component

```sh
sh <ANALYTICS_HOME>/bin/dashboard.sh
```

Once started, access `https://hostname:9643/analytics-dashboard` and click on Monitoring Dashboard to view the Alerts. Find the official [documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/learn/analytics/viewing-api-statistics/monitoring-dashboard/#alert-summary) for more reference.